# Issue with OpenRAM installation

Tags: docker, ubuntu-20.04

I try to install [OpenRAM](https://github.com/VLSIDA/OpenRAM) and got the [issue](https://github.com/VLSIDA/OpenRAM/issues/149) which seems nobody faced before

My steps are:

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/VLSIDA/OpenRAM.git
cd OpenRAM//docker/
sudo make build
```

got the following listing in terminal

```
docker build -t vlsida/openram-ubuntu:2022-07-22 -f Dockerfile . | tee -i openram-ubuntu.log
tee: openram-ubuntu.log: Permission denied
Sending build context to Docker daemon   12.8kB
Step 1/74 : FROM ubuntu:20.04
 ---> 20fffa419e3a
Step 2/74 : ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1ab1b2479718
Step 3/74 : RUN ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles /etc/localtime
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d298d3442c85
Step 4/74 : RUN echo "America/Los_Angeles" > /etc/timezone
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e2c892d3d4d4
Step 5/74 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b293f883d92e
Step 6/74 : RUN apt-get --no-install-recommends -y upgrade
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9b8a3d73d4dd
Step 7/74 : RUN apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y build-essential git ssh vim gosu autoconf automake libtool bison flex
 ---> Running in d3547986a1de
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package build-essential
E: Unable to locate package git
E: Unable to locate package ssh
E: Unable to locate package vim
E: Unable to locate package gosu
E: Unable to locate package autoconf
E: Unable to locate package automake
E: Unable to locate package libtool
E: Unable to locate package bison
E: Unable to locate package flex
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y build-essential git ssh vim gosu autoconf automake libtool bison flex' returned a non-zero code: 100
make: *** [Makefile:10: build] Error 1
```

Are there any suggestions? Forgive me If I'm doing something stupid, but I'm not experienced with Linux and docker.

Comment: Is this something you're writing yourself, or just software you're trying to install?  You generally need to `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install` in a single command; if the `update` step comes from the cache it could reference package URLs that no longer exist.  I'd also be surprised if your application uses `ssh` or `vim` at all and I'd probably remove those from the image.

Comment: This is the O/S software I want to install. Once I've added `update` (if I get you right way) I still have same error. `The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y build-essential git gosu autoconf automake libtool bison flex' returned a non-zero code: 100
make: *** [Makefile:10: build] Error 1`. I want to stress, that this S/W installed by many users, and nobody have experienced such an issue. It looks like some specific issue on my side.